# Uploading file to remote server from android isn't working

Tags: php, android, file-upload

I am a new Android learner. I was trying to upload a textfile from SD card to a remote server. I have written the PHP script in such a way that If the file is set it will do file operations and response "Success!" else it will response "File is not set!". Here is the PHP Script -

```php
<?php

    if(isset($_FILES["file"])){
        /* Do file operations */
        echo "Success!";
    }
    else{
        die("file is not set!");
    }

?>
```

It always responses "file is not set!". May be its not recognizing the "file" index in $_FILES[]. Can't understand why!

**Here is the android part for uploading file:**

```java
/* Location of the file */
String filePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/sample.txt";

/* URL of the PHP script for file processing */
String URL = "http://myserver/upload.php";

/* New HTTP Client */
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

/* Post */
HttpPost post = new HttpPost(URL);

/* Create file from file path */
File file = new File(filePath);
FileBody fileBody = new FileBody(file);

/* Make MultipartEntity from File Body and send */
MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
reqEntity.addPart("file", fileBody);

/* Execute Http post request and get response */
HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();

if(resEntity != null){
    /* Make response entity into string to get string response */
    String responseString = EntityUtils.toString(resEntity);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), responseString, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

**And here is full PHP part:**

```php
<?php

    if(isset($_FILES["file"])){
        $file_path = "upload/" . basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]);

        if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $file_path)){
            echo "Success!";
        }
        else{
            echo "Failed!";
        }
    }
    else{
        die("file is not set!");
    }

?>
```

Comment: if you use image file then you can convert it to string and then send this string to server and when you need the image then retrieve the string from server and decode it to image in in your app